# Market extension installed but not available in https://dev.azure.com/

Tags: azure-devops, marketplace

For Azure DevOps, a couple extensions installed from marketplace successfully (use Chrome browser). But I can't see menus from those extension as if they were not installed. Do I need to turn on something to see those feature? For example, I installed "Enhanced Export", "Wiki PDF Exprt", "Word item visualization"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> But I can't see menus from those extension as if they were not
> installed. Do I need to turn on something to see those feature?

For the extension `Word item visualization`, there is an obvious option **Visualize** on the workitem to show that we have installed the extension:

[image]

If you still could not see this option after installed the extension `Word item visualization`, please go to the `Organization Settings`->`Settings`->`Task restrictions`, check if the option **Disable Marketplace tasks** is enable:

[image]